# What's the difference between FormView and CreateView

Tags: django

In the official documentation,
formView is A view that displays a form. On error, redisplays the form with validation errors; on success, redirects to a new URL.
createView is A view that displays a form for creating an object, redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and saving the object.
//(maybe my English isn't good enough)So if I want to make a generic view that users to create a new category I should use createview over formview right? I wasn't sure, so I tried both ways and both of them gives me same error:as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

With form view:

## for adding category

```
class CategoryFormView(FormView):
    form_class = CategoryForm
    template_name = 'main/add_category.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('category', args=[self.object.slug]))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add any extra context data needed for form here.
        return context
```

with createView

```
#for adding category
class CategoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    form_class = CategoryForm
    template_name = 'main/add_category.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      #setting
      self.object.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('category', args=[self.object.slug]))

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(CategoryCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Finally this is my urls.py

```
url(r'^add_category/', views.CategoryCreateView.as_view, name='add-category'),
```

Edit: sorry it works, just forgot to put parenthesis next to url, but can you please tell me the difference between createview and formview? when should use what?

Edit2:

```
def index(request):

    categories = Category.objects.order_by('likes')[:5]
    latest_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    popular_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-views')
    hot_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-score')[:25]
    context_dict = {
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'popular_posts': popular_posts,
        'hot_posts': hot_posts,
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context_dict)
#for single-post page
#we use uuslug 
def post(request, slug):
    single_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    single_post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
    single_post.save()      # and save it
    context_dict = {
      'single_post' :single_post,
    }
  
    return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
#for category page
#we use slugfield this time 
def category(request, category_name_slug):
  context_dict = {}
  try:
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    context_dict['category_name'] = category.name

    posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
    context_dict['posts'] = posts
    context_dict['category'] = category
  except Category.DoesNotExist:
    pass

  return render(request, 'main/category.html', context_dict)
```

Edit 3

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from main import views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    #url(r'^add_post/', views.add_post, name='add_post'),
    url(r'^add_post/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-add'),

    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),


    url(r'^add_category/$', CategoryCreateView.as_view(), name='add-category'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post'),

    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category'),
    
]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. You were missing function call in:

```
url(r'^add_category/', views.CategoryCreateView.as_view(), name='add-category'),
```

As for your other question, `CreateView` and `FormView` are pretty similar, except `CreateView` is more specific implementation of `FormView`.

`FormView` is really meant to handle:

- display form on GET
- display form with errors on POST
- redirect to a different page when form has no errors

`CreateView` on the other hand is identical to `FormView` except it does this as well:

- it is assumed it is dealing with a `ModelForm` form which implements `save()` method
- before redirecting to a different page, the form's `save()` is called which creates the model
- the created model is stored in `self.object` so that you can use it in `get_success_url` to generate a URL for the created object (e.g. redirect to object detail page)

Classy views is an awesome resource to inspect Django class-based-views. Here are links for both classes:

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/
https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Check our the `form_valid` methods where you will see the biggest diff.

As for picking which to use, I think it all depends on your scenario. If you are trying to create model instances via `ModelForm` then `CreateView` is probably better for you and if you are doing something generic then `FormView` is probably a better fit.

---

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'latest_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at'),
            'popular_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-views'),
            'hot_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-score')[:25],
            'categories': Category.objects.order_by('likes')[:5],
        })
        return context

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'single_post'
    template_name = 'main/post.html'
    # note that these are already "slug" by default
    pk_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = seuper(PostView, self).get_object(queryset)
        obj.views += 1
        obj.save()
        return obj

class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'main/category.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'
    # note that these are already "slug" by default
    pk_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_context_date(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            # really no need to put category_name in context
            # as you can simply do {{ category.name }} in your template

            # you can use relations to query related data
            'posts': self.object.post_set.all()
        })
        return context
```

Comment: thank you, I should use createView then. Do people use generic view just because it's more simple?DRY principle? because for my index, category,post view they are more complicated than the one I posted above, and I think it will get more complicated using generic view for them. I will post my index,category,post functions, if you can take a look a t them I will really be appreciated.

Comment: If you are not sure what to use, I would recommend `CreateView` since it simplifies your life. Once you use it for a bit, you will start coming across limitations which is when I would recommend to start using one of the more base classes such as `FormView` or even simply `View` when you really need to do something custom.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, do you mind taking look at my index,category,post functions I'm trying to transform them into generic  view but I'm having trouble because they have more functionality

Comment: In your 3 pasted views, none of them actually create anything or use forms. I would recommend to look into `DetailView` which is what you are trying to do. You can see more about it in https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/ or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#DetailView

Comment: Hmm I looked into it and still not sure how I should manage them, for example inside index functions there are multiple in context_dict, and inside post there is function to increment views, and inside category it filters out posts that belong to other category

Comment: Sorry i'm still a beginner and this is my first project in django

Comment: Thats perfectly fine! Everyone starts somewhere. I would not worry too much about optimizing your code. What you pasted in the question is a good start. Trying to use all the bells and whistles right in your first project will only confuse you (trust me, I tried that). Just try to implement required functionality and over time you will learn all the useful shortcuts Django has to provide.

Comment: Also if you are looking for a good education resource I would HIGHLY recommend Django Unleashed by Andrew Pinkham. I wish it was out when I started Django. I just got mine and it is an amazing book. Its basically Django tutorial with 1 billion examples and way more informative. http://www.amazon.com/Django-Unleashed-Andrew-Pinkham/dp/0321985079

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, if you have time do you mind transforming my functions to generic view? I think I can understand them once I see how they are transformed.(I don't see the advantage of transforming them in the case like this but unfortunately most examples use class based view) if you don't want to, that's totally fine too ^^

Comment: thanks I've been meaning to do some django tutorials, I did tango with django/ django girls/django offical docu tutotiral/try django1.8(youtube) and almost done with my first project. I'm making reddit clone and just need to implement voting system and image scraping

Comment: OMG thank you so much, I will review it and post what I've understood asap

Comment: Hello, I tried the ones you provided but this gives me error. Can't even login, it says NoReverseMatch and Reverse for 'add_category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: those errors are outside the scope of your original question. if you are having more issues, you can ask another SO question or try to find existing relevant question.

Comment: Hello, yeah I did but I didn't get any answer. So I switched back because I thought some of them are wrong.-I understand the code tho

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146950/noreversematch-at-reverse-for-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments?noredirect=1#comment56042464_34146950