# Django Form not saving for Custom User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-registration

I have a register user form which is doing all the validation as expected. However, it is not saving. I am not able to figure out the reason. How do I debug it ? Any help ? I am a newbie to forms and formviews any good document with example would really help me.

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    country_code = forms.IntegerField()
    #schools = school.objects.all()
    #school_name  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=school.objects.distinct())
    MIN_LENGTH = 4
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','country_code','phone_number', 'password1', 'password2',
                  'full_name' ]

    
    def clean_phone_number(self):
        phone_number = self.data.get('phone_number')
        print(phone_number)
        if User.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _("Another user with this phone number already exists"))
        if len(phone_number) == 10 and phone_number.isdigit():
            pass
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _("Invalid Phone Number"))
        return phone_number
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("saving")
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        print('Saving user with country_code', user.country_code)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Views.py

```
class RegisterView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'register-2.html'
    
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_message = "One-Time password sent to your registered mobile number.\
                        The verification code is valid for 10 minutes."
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        full_name=self.request.POST["full_name"]
                              
        user = form.save()
        print(user.id)
                    
        username = self.request.POST['username']
        password = self.request.POST['password1']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        
        kwargs = {'user': user}
        self.request.method = 'POST'
        print("User created")
        


   The print in clean_phone_number works however, save does not work
```

Comment: try using CreateView instead of FormView, it hase a save() method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125345/whats-the-difference-between-formview-and-createview#:~:text=As%20for%20your%20other%20question,when%20form%20has%20no%20errors

Answer (score 0):

I had issue in the my form. One of the field was disabled and the value was not captured because of that.
However to identify that I used

```
 def form_invalid(self,form):
            # Add action to invalid form phase
            messages.error(self.request, form.errors)
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```